# Ruby on Rails - Paperclip - NoHandleError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, file-upload, paperclip

I got an error while setting up a polymorphic file upload with the paperclip gem on Ruby on Rails.
In the following, I will show you the relevant code parts.

I've set up a _form partial:

```
<%= form_for(@test_run, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 columns">

    <%= fields_for :attachment do |attachment_fields| %>
        <%= attachment_fields.file_field :attachment %><br />
    <% end %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.submit t('buttons.general.save'), :class => "button slim", data: {disable_with: "#{t('buttons.general.disable')}"}, :alt => t('buttons.general.save'),:title => t('buttons.general.save') %>
  </div>
</div>
```

My attachment model contains the file validation:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => :true

  has_attached_file :attachment
  validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, content_type: /\A(image|application)\/.*\z/
end
```

In the attachment controller I whitelist the following parameters:

```
def attachment_params
  params.require(:attachment).permit(:name, :user_id, :attachable_id, :attachable_type, :attachedfile)
end
```

The attachment should be attached to a test run. Here is the test run model:

```
class TestRun < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test_object

  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
end
```

The create method and the private methods of the test runs controller could be relevant, too:

```
def create
  @test_run = TestRun.new(test_run_params)

  attachment = Attachment.create(:attachable_id => @test_run_id, :attachment => params[:attachment])

  render text: @test_run.attachments.first.inspect
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_test_run
    @test_run = TestRun.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def test_run_params
    params.require(:test_run).permit(:name, :test_object_id, :attachment, :start_time, :end_time, :test_demands, :allowed_bug_types, :max_testers, :test_language, :postprocessing_time, :test_standards, :target_tester, :target_devices)
  end
```

To give you a completely overview, here is the attachment migration file:

```
class CreateAttachments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :attachments do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :attachable_id
      t.string :attachable_type

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Now, when I run this, fill out the form and select a valid file and submit the form after this, I receive the following error:
**Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError in TestRunsController#create**
Ok, somehow, stackoverflow shrinks the error message, so I put it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/c0tjsMCL).

If hope, someone of you could help me, as I am on this point since days of researching for bugs.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run migration:

```
rails generate paperclip attachment attachment
```

in your view:

```
<%= fields_for :attachment do |field| %>
    <%= field.file_field :attachment %><br />
<% end %>
```

your `attachment_params`

```
def attachment_params
  params.require(:attachment).permit(:name, :user_id, :attachable_id, :attachable_type, :attachment)
end
```

your method `create`

```
def create

  @test_run = TestRun.new(test_run_params)

  attachment = Attachment.create(attachment_params)

  render text: @test_run.attachments.first.inspect
end
```

you must also included in this controller method `attachment_params`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this leads to the same error.

Comment: Can you show also code from your `TestRunController ` ?

Comment: I've added it to the question. Only the create method and the private methods should be relevant, as the error occurs while creating a test run.